# Rotation Value ist not the same as given in the driver output

Tags: python, modifiers, drivers

I am just trying to set up a dynamic circular array of objects. To keep it as dynamic as possible, I want to make my helpers empty z rotation driven by a driver. The Scripted Expression looks like this:  360/count while count is the count value set in the arrays modifier on my object.

The final value calculated in the driver is correct.(45 in case I have a count of 8). The actual value set in the rotation property is different. See the Screenshot below.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While all angles entered into the transform input field are interpreted as degrees, when you set the value in a script or driver it's interpreted as radians.

[image: radians vs degrees]

Your driver sets the rotation to 45 radians which is about 2578 degrees. The expression `2*pi/count` should provide you with the desired angle.

Comment: or `radians(360 / count)`