# Drivers seem to only use radians

Tags: drivers

Simple driver:

15+(15*(sin(frame)))

Should return between 0 and 30 but forces 180 most of the time.
I've tried both:

15+(15*(sin(degrees(frame))))

15+(15*(degrees(sin(frame))))

Neither work and yes I have changed to degrees in units. Does nothing.
Is there any fix?

I would be able to do more intricate animations if I could control the numbers effectively,
otherwise I have to keyframe or settle on something looking horrible.

Thanks.

Comment: Describe why it doesn't work.  Surely `15+(15*(sin(degrees(frame))))` is 15 on frame 0 and 30 at frame 90.  If you are driving an angle (and 0 to 30 is the degrees result) may wish to wrap the whole thing in radians `radians(15+(15*(sin(degrees(frame)))))`

Comment: Related: [About driver rotation Degree and Radian](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/159557/78972), [Rotation Value ist not the same as given in the driver output](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/110468/78972),

Comment: oops, degrees should be radians in comment above.`15 * (1 + sin(radians(frame)))`  `

Comment: Yes! Your numbers are correct, but it's still not working.

Comment: I tested this 15+(15*(sin(i))) on Khan academy with a for loop just to verify and it worked 1st time. I need to learn how to do this in python, I guess.